# How to Lower MySQL Memory Usage without Restarting MySQLd

Tags: mysql, memory, flush

MySQL 5.1.63 takes a growing memory usage as time in the Debian Sqeeze OS.

Here is my top output:

[image]

At the moment MySQLd uses 732Mb resident memory (RES column), VIRT 855M. But it starts at about 330Mb of RAM two days before.

Unfortunately some day it reaches at the peak of 1.2G by some unidentified bad query, and never goes down... causing server down.

I tried the following stuffs to lower the VIRT (virtual memory) and RES (Resident RAM) using mysql console, without restarting the MySQLd server, but no success:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES;

mysql> FLUSH QUERY CACHE;

mysql> RESET QUERY CACHE;
```

The MySQL RAM usage remains 732m.

Any idea ?

Answer (score -2):

Read this: http://www.chriscalender.com/?p=1278

Open my.cnf and add this at the end: performance_schema=0

Restart your services. From 620MB I have now 38MB memory used.

Comment: I've checked this configuration with performance_schema=0, as a result, there is no effects as my version of MySQL is of MySQL 5.1.63, performance schema is not available. Thanks for your time.